# Decrease indexPath by one with sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with sections, I want to know the previous item of a given `IndexPath`, I know I can use this

`NSIndexPath* newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:oldIndexPath.row -1 inSection:oldIndexPath.section];`

If I had only one section, But since I have a few sections, how can I know the previous item in the tableview (if the item is first in his section I want to get the last item of the previous section.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could go with something like that: (replace `self.tableView` with just `tableView` if u use this code in a method that receives an `UITableView` object as argument):

```
NSIndexPath* newIndexPath = nil;
// check for row being the first one in this section
if (oldIndexPath.row == 0) {
    // check for this section having a previous section
    if (oldIndexPath.section > 0) {
        // get number of rows of the previous section
        NSInteger numberOfRows = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection : oldIndexPath.section - 1];
        newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: numberOfRows - 1 inSection: oldIndexPath.section - 1];
    }
} else { // if the row is not the first in this section
    // get the indexPath for the previous row in this section
    newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:oldIndexPath.row - 1 inSection: oldIndexPath.section];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've ended up using something else but this works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

If (row - 1) is less than 0, subtract one from section.
If (section - 1) is also less than 0, you were at the top of the table.  Otherwise, find that section's last row.
You must have that information since you provide it to the table view.